# Germany Work Visa

Tags: schengen-visas

My company has it's office in Germany and I will be travelling from India for 2 weeks related to work(No Business Meetings). What type of visa I should apply for working there?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the relation of your trip to your work. Generally speaking, the usual Schengen visa does not permit you to work, but there are a few exceptions which should be listed in the application and then on the visa sticker. Examples are training courses, or the servicing of equipment made by your company that is installed in Germany.

You might inquire at Expatriates Stack Exchange even if it is a short trip, because they know about work permits.

Answer (score 0):

For a trip of two weeks, no matter what the purpose is, the correct type of visa to apply for is a **uniform Schengen short-stay visa**.

This visa *has no bearing at all* on whether you will be allowed to *work*. Work for non-EU/EEA nationals is a matter for each member state's national law, and not regulated by Schengen visas at all.

Depending on the precise kind of work you plan to do, you *may or may not* need to apply for a work permit from the German authorities *in addition to* a visa. Your employer's HR people ought to know whether that is the case -- or if they don't, the company ought to hire a German lawyer to find out for them. Any halfway well-run company should not make it your task to research that for yourself!